# Tab's yposition is inconsistent across TabTypes

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the SOAP API to specify the positions of tabs on a document using their x and y coordinates. I've noticed that when I use "FullName" or "DateSigned" TabTypes the tab ends up around an inch higher on the PDF than if I used the "SignHere" or "InitialHere" TabTypes.

I apparently can't post an image of what I'm seeing because this is my first post, but is there a reason why the same value for the Tab.yposition property would create different results for different TabTypes?

Comment: This might be a bug with DocuSign.  In my initial tests I'm seeing the same behavior, will inquire with the company...

Comment: Bug confirmed and logged with DocuSign, bug id 30539

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can be notified when the issue is corrected or else track the issue myself?

Comment: sorry but I don't believe so.  This is an internal DocuSign bug but I'll try to update this post as soon as the fix goes out.  Might take a few builds...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but it had to do with a bug that was fixed long ago. The original problem about the tab placement is therefore fixed. I still would recommend considering using the REST API and not the SOAP API if possible.